# Elixir interpreter error

Tags: elixir

I was following [elixir getting started](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html) where it says run:

```
iex> i 'hello'
```

so I ran:

```
iex(1)> i 'hello'
```

and got:

```
 ** (CompileError) iex:2: undefined function i/1
```

elixir version:
`Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false] Interactive Elixir (1.1.0-dev)`

Comment: What version of Elixir did you install? Looks like you have an old version.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install elixir` on ubuntu: `Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.1.0-dev)`

Comment: Yep, that's an old version. [`i` was added in 1.2](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/806c2da15c38120542df46fcc9853b7ee2c4fe8b). Try installing the latest version using the instructions here: http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like

Comment: @Dogbert thanx it's fixed :), you want to write the answer? or should I do it?

Comment: @yonatan you should accept Dogbert's answer for people who look at this in the future.

Answer (score 17):

The function `IEx.Helpers.i/1`, which the guide you linked to uses, [was added in Elixir 1.2.0](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/806c2da15c38120542df46fcc9853b7ee2c4fe8b). You need to install Elixir 1.2.0 or later version to use it.

see http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like, for installation guide.