# elixir - when I do something like `i 123` I get a compile error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to use `i` and when I do something like `i 123` I get `** (CompileError) iex:3: undefined function i/1`

Can someone please help me out?  What am I doing wrong?

edit:  here's a screenshot of my console.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elixir interpreter error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483390/elixir-interpreter-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you been putting the `i 123` in your actual code file or using it in an IEX terminal?

If in IEx it should just work out of the box, e.g.:

```
iex(2)> i 123
Term
  123
Data type
  Integer
Reference modules
  Integer
iex(3)>
```

However, if you want to use it in your code, say a method definition, then you would need to use the full module name:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def method do
    IEx.Helpers.i 123
  end
end


iex(1)> MyModule.method
Term
  123
Data type
  Integer
Reference modules
  Integer
```

Or if you are going to be using it multiple times throughout your code, then add an `import IEx.Helpers` to your module definition.

```
defmodule MyModule do
  import IEx.Helpers

  def method do
    i 123
  end

end
```

Which Will work just as above:

```
iex(2)> MyModule.method
Term
  123
Data type
  Integer
Reference modules
  Integer
```

Comment: Ah right, you might need to update your elixir version from 1.1-dev to 1.3. Otherwise, you might have to run `import IEx.Helpers` when you start the IEx session @user1354934

Comment: please pardon my ignorance but what's the best way to upgrade my elixir version?  I installed it using apt-get.  Thanks

Comment: This answer shows you how to ugrade a package [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/754074/how-can-i-apt-get-update-1-package) but basically `sudo apt-get install elixir`

Comment: dang so now I am getting some more errors :(  basically i removed everything and followed the getting started on elixir.  now i get a BEAM doesn't match :(

Comment: not sure why i am having so much issues :( i will try to remove all erlang stuff off my PC and try again hopefully works

Comment: @user1354934 hmm visit this link [here](http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like) and scroll down to the 'ubuntu' section and follow those instrucitons there to get the correct erlang installed

Comment: figured out the issue is that i have linux mint 18 and the distribution i have to use is wheezy and it works now... with right version :(